# Using javascript/jquery, validate URL that should have http or https and www

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please advice how to validate a url that should have http or https and www in it

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried to [search](http://www.google.com.ua/#source=hp&q=url+validation+javascript&oq=url+validation+ja&aq=2&aqi=g2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1648l5935l0l7190l9l8l0l2l2l0l153l657l2.4l6&fp=2c4748e2a65232a4&biw=1280&bih=888)

Comment: yes, what i couldn't find is a script that checks for both http and www

Answer (score 4):

Try to use that function:

```
(function isURL(s) {
    var regexp = /http(s?):\/\/www\.[A-Za-z0-9\.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{3}/;
     return regexp.test(s);
})("https://www.google.com")
```

you may play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fedor/HueKJ/)

Comment: This fails for `http://www.google.co.uk/`. I honestly think your regexp is too extensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 ^(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?



var re = /^(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/;

alert(re.test(yourString));
```

[Test it at this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkGdX/).

[Found at RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=96).

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
function checkhttpWww(s) {
     var reg = /http(s?):\/\/www/;
      return reg.test(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_correct(x) {
    return /^http[s]?:\/\/www\./.test(x);
}
```